# How to reset the wordpress plugins without deactivate the plugin

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins

```
function set_copyright_options() {
    delete_option('ptechsolcopy_notice');
    delete_option('ptechsolcopy_reserved');

    add_option('ptechsolcopy_notice','Copyright &copy;');
    add_option('ptechsolcopy_reserved','All Rights Reserved');

}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'set_copyright_options');
```

Hi I use the code to make it plugin default while deactivate and activate plugin .But i need the options to make it using the reset button in the admin side to make it default without deactivate the plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`add_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) to create the page. In the callback function, add a form with a reset button:

```
function reset_my_options() {
  add_menu_page( 'Reset Options', 'Reset Options', 'manage_options', 'reset-options', 'reset_option_page' );
}

function reset_option_page() {
if ( isset( $_POST['reset_options'] ) && $_POST['reset_options'] === 'true' ) {

delete_option('ptechsolcopy_notice');
delete_option('ptechsolcopy_reserved');

}
  ?>

  <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Reset options</h2>

    <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin.php?page=reset-options' ); ?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Click to reset plugin options" style="float:left;" />
      <input type="hidden" name="reset_options" value="true" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

You can also add [nonces](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) to it for further security.

BTW, you could have use [`update_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) in your plugin activation instead of `delete_option` and `add_option`.